# sql with logical operation

Tags: sql, database, algorithm, t-sql

hi here is my small problem . im working on sql and i have some logical operations to get the values from the sql database . i have the screen shot . plz refer it

[image]

in that i have four query in different combinations. if  you take **1 and 2** both gives me the same answer and **3 and 4** gives me different answer . Now my question in i have two  operators **1.OR and 2.And Not** and the filters while means the variable may be **n** . **now my question is**

1. i want to get the different combinations for the given variables
2. and have to eliminate the possibility which gives me same result

any algorithms coding are welcome

can anyone help me soon

**update**

for more clear

if i have four **values** namely **a,b,c,d**
then i have to frame the diff combinations like

**1. (a or b) and not( c or d)**

**2.  a or ( b and not c ) or d**

i have updated my question .. like this i have to generate different combination and get the answer

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compare multiple rows within a set you can't use the logic you showed in your example, because a single row can't have multiple values within a singe column.

A common solution is to use aggregation over this group of rows and move the conditions into CASEs in HAVING checking if there's any row paasing the check:

e.g. your 2nd select,

```
(code = 40660 or code = 40900) and not code = 41180
```

can be simplified to

```
(code in (40660, 40900)) and code <> 41180
```

Translated into HAVING:

```
SELECT grpcol
FROM tab
GROUP BY grpcol
HAVING 
   -- any row with a code 40660 or 40900 --> result > 0 --> TRUE
  SUM(CASE WHEN code IN (40660, 40900) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
AND  
  -- any row with code 41180 --> result > 0 --> FALSE
  SUM(CASE WHEN code <> 41180 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```

Comment: did you noticed my question that i have asked i want to generate the all different kind of possibilities . "i don't know which is the correct result set, but you should know it :-)" this statement has no meaning here . coz i have to generate all the diff  possibilities and result set .

Comment: In your example your using the same column m.code for all your comparisons and one column in one row can't have multiple values. Those who downvote should check the boolean algebra knowledge.

Comment: different values . not variable

Comment: I think you want something different: you got a set of rows and want to know if the rows within that set fullfill your conditions, i.e. m.code is not from a single row but multiple rows?

Comment: Rewrote my answer based on the new info :-)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37646/discussion-between-backtrack-and-dnoeth)